# How to add stream target in wowza using rest api into facebook?

Tags: rest, api, wowza

I want to create facebook stream through wowza rest api (/v2/servers/{serverName}/vhosts/{vhostName}/applications/{appName}/pushpublish/mapentries).

```
Parameters `{
    "shoutcast.destination": "",
    "icecast2.public": false,
    "akamai.destinationServer": "",
    "shoutcast.icq": "",
    "facebook.eventSourceName": "",
    "timeToLive": 0,
    "password": "",
    "facebook.destType": "",
    "rtpWrap": false,
    "icecast2.name": "",
    "akamai.hostId": "",
    "icecast2.icq": "",
    "host": "",
    "connectionFlashVersion": "",
    "cupertino.renditions": "",
    "facebook.title": "",
    "debugPackets": false,
    "shoutcast.public": false,
    "shoutcast.aim": "",
    "profile": "",
    "icecast2.description": "",
    "sessionStatus": "",
    "shoutcast.metaname": "",
    "icecast2.genre": "",
    "facebook.destId": "",
    "queryString": "",
    "akamai.eventName": "",
    "version": "",
    "shoutcast.name": "",
    "sendStreamCloseCommands": false,
    "port": 0,
    "sendFCPublish": false,
    "icecast2.aim": "",
    "http.playlistCount": 0,
    "http.playlistTimeout": 0,
    "facebook.destName": "",
    "audioPort": "",
    "icecast2.metaname": "",
    "sourceStreamName": "",
    "connectionCode": "",
    "localBindAddress": "",
    "shoutcast.protocol": "",
    "debugLogChildren": false,
    "serverName": "",
    "adaptiveStreaming": false,
    "facebook.eventSourceType": "",
    "enabled": false,
    "shoutcast.irc": "",
    "sendReleaseStream": false,
    "shoutcast.url": "",
    "icecast2.irc": "",
    "facebook.description": "",
    "debugLog": false,
    "shoutcast.genre": "",
    "akamai.streamId": "",
    "akamai.hdNetwork": false,
    "adaptiveGroups": "",
    "saveFieldList": [
      ""
  ],
    "http.playlistAcrossSessions": false,
    "secureTokenSharedSecret": "",
    "http.fakePosts": false,
    "sendSSL": false,
    "sendOriginalTimecodes": false,
    "icecast2.destination": "",
    "facebook.accessToken": "",
    "userName": "",
    "facebook.privacy": "",
    "streamName": "",
    "removeDefaultAppInstance": false,
    "videoPort": "",
    "http.writerDebug": false,
    "icecast2.url": "",
    "akamai.sendToBackupServer": false,
    "destinationServer": "",
    "application": "",
    "entryName": "",
    "streamWaitTimeout": 0,
    "appInstance": "",
    "originalTimecodeThreshold": "",
    "autoStartTranscoder": false,
    "sanjose.representationId": ""
}`
```

As per the api doc their are lot of parameter which I have pass during the api call but they didn't mention proper document for that.

Please help me out :)

Comment: Facebook Live API requires that a unique application ID be used to generate access tokens. This token negotiation is handled from the Wowza Streaming Engine Manager UI when you create/update stream targets (launching a Facebook login window), and is then added as a property in the Wowza stream target to allow it to publish to the Facebook page. The tokens cannot be created from the REST API. You will need to handle the token management with Facebook API externally. Once you have the necessary access tokens, you can populate this into your Wowza stream target via the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Following parameters can be used to create a Facebook stream target through the REST API.
(/v2/servers/{serverName}/vhosts/{vhostName}/applications/{appName}/pushpublish/mapentries)

```
{
  "entryName": "fb-api",
  "profile": "rtmp-facebook",
  "sourceStreamName": "{StreamName}",
  "facebook.title": "Live Test",
  "facebook.destType": "timeline",
  "facebook.destId": "{DestinationPageId}",
  "facebook.destName": "My Timeline",
  "facebook.description": "This is Wowza live test",
  "facebook.accessToken": "{FacebookAccessToken}",
  "facebook.privacy": "onlyMe",
  "extraOptions": {
    "destinationName": "facebook"
  },
  "enabled": true
}
```

If you have access to the file system where Wowza is installed, you can see all stream targets which are created in the \conf\{appName}\PushPublishMap.txt file. You can configure a stream target through the Wowza streaming engine interface and open this file to get an idea about the required parameters for a particular type of stream target using the REST API.

Please note that this is valid for Wowza Streaming Engine 4.5 and above.

Comment: Thanks Aslam I'm doing in your way It helps me.

Comment: Hi! Ayaz i am using wowza 4.6 is this solution still valid?? i am doing the same but getting error in stream target. seems not accepting the token.
also when login with facebook using wowza streaming engine the token that generated in Publish map file is strange e.g "ENC-xxxx"
in logs wowza is throwing this error 
PushPublishFacebookUtil.getTokenInfo: GET path:v2.6/debug_token result:400

Comment: Hi Usama, it should still work for version 4.6. Please make sure that the Facebook access token you're using has the necessary permissions to post videos.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer already provided by @AyazAslam, with a few small caveats:

- The "facebook.destType" parameter could be "timeline",
  "page", "group", or "event", so the "facebook.destId" parameter value should more generically be:

  ```
  "facebook.destId": "{DestinationId}"
  ```
- The "facebook.privacy" parameter actually only applies to posting to a
  "timeline".  It has no effect on other destination types.
- The Facebook app that is used to create the access token must have it's
  "Require App Secret" option disabled since Wowza cannot provide another app's app
  secret in the Facebook API calls it makes.